# How to use analytics tracking with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I found this code from google in order to add tracking to whatever link I want.

```
<script>
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>

<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>
```

Since I need to run the click using jQuery the question is:
How can I do the onclick outbound from my jQuery file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I'm fully understanding what you're trying to do here, but the example above isn't using jQuery.  The code between the script tags is pure javascript and is being called as a result of the onClick() event on your anchor tag.

If you want to use jQuery to track all links clicked and eliminate the need for using the onClick event on each anchor tag, place the following code before the ending body tag on all pages that you want to track link clicks.

```js
$('a').on('click', function(){
  ga('send', 
     'event',
     'Link Clicked',  // event category - can have any name
     window.location.href,  // page where the link was clicked
     $(this).attr('href')   // href of the link clicked
  );
});
```